# onblur/onfocus textarea default value entering into db php

Tags: php, jquery, html, database

I have seen this talked about but never answered.  Maybe it has and I'm not sure where to find it.

I have several textareas and the onblur/onfocus are working great, but when the textarea is left empty, the "default value" is inserted into the database.   How can I prevent that from happening??  I do not want "Add Public Notes Here!!" to be entered into the db.

```
    <td colspan="4"><textarea name="comments" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
```

Add Public Notes Here!!

Can anybody push me towards the right direction.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't have the PHP code posted that inserts it into your database, so it's hard to tell you exactly what to do, but basically somewhere above that you will need to put a conditional that resets the value of the textarea submission if it contains the default string. Basically something like

```
<?php (isset($_POST['comments'] && $_POST['comments'] == 'Add Public Notes Here!!') {
    $comments = ''; } else { $comments = $_POST['comments']; } ?>
```

Of course, rather than `$comments` you need to use whatever variable contains the value that is getting inserted into your database. I can't help you much more unless you show more code.

Comment: And before anyone code golfs me I know you can do that more concisely, but I selected this for readability and to illustrate better what's going on.

Comment: Sorry...  Please look at this page for full source code.    http://www.rainbow-logistics.com/sample.php @palintropos

Comment: Well it looks to me like the code I gave you will work as advertised, with two caveats. One, of course, you need to remove the `<?php ?>` tags. They were included for completeness in my example but this will already be within a pair. Two, you need to change the line `GetSQLValueString($_POST['comments'], "text");` to `GetSQLValueString($comments, "text");` for it to have any effect, and of course insert the code above before this line.

Comment: As an aside, I'm going to assume from the fact that you have so much javascript form validation that this form is exposed to some average-ish users, meaning you should probably reconsider doing something better with the error handling than `or die(mysql_error())`. That's fine if your form is intended for a computer science lab or an otherwise fairly tech-savvy audience, but you could achieve something a little nicer by logging the error with `trigger_error` (and disabling error reporting, of course) and a nice "technical difficulties" message for users.

Comment: Works like a charm... WOW @palintropos is the BOMB!! Send me an email and I will send you a login for you to see.  scott@rainbow-logistics.com

Answer (score 0):

You should check the default values on form submit event and empty the textareas have that

Comment: Do i have to have some javascript with this?? @peter Im sorry but I dont have an on form submit event...  Enlighten me??

Comment: He's referring to (but not explaining how to) using JavaScript's onSubmit handler to do what I explained how to do below using PHP. The server-side solution is probably preferable because users can always disable JavaScript.

Comment: hang on, i will send you the code.  Just busy right now.  Thanks palintropos